# Как выбрать все хэштеги с помощью regex

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Строка:

> En pocos días recibiremos en SAICA la nueva TRICITY 125✔️ ¿Quieres conocerla más?\n\nCon un motor de última generación Blue Core de 125cc que cumple la norma EURO 5 y un sistema nuevo Stop & Start, el scooter de tres ruedas ofrece un rendimiento potente con muy poco consumo.\nSus dos ruedas delanteras inclinables aportan una mayor sensación de estabilidad y confianza al tomar curvas y además la puedes conducir con el permiso de conducir B.\n\n¡Moverte con la Tricicty 125 no puede ser más sencillo! \n\n#saicamotos #tuconcesionariooficial #yamaha #valencia #tricity125 #yamahatricity #new #yamahavalencia #motorcycle #yamahamotor #tuesday #motorbike

Нужен массив хештегов

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать с помощью регулярного выражения

```js
let str = `En pocos días recibiremos en SAICA la nueva TRICITY 125✔️ ¿Quieres conocerla más?\n\nCon un motor de última generación Blue Core de 125cc que cumple la norma EURO 5 y un sistema nuevo Stop & Start, el scooter de tres ruedas ofrece un rendimiento potente con muy poco consumo.\nSus dos ruedas delanteras inclinables aportan una mayor sensación de estabilidad y confianza al tomar curvas y además la puedes conducir con el permiso de conducir B.\n\n¡Moverte con la Tricicty 125 no puede ser más sencillo! \n\n#saicamotos #tuconcesionariooficial #yamaha #valencia #tricity125 #yamahatricity #new #yamahavalencia #motorcycle #yamahamotor #tuesday #motorbike`;
let result = str.match(/#[\p{L}]+/ugi);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Насколько я помню JS не поддерживает  `\p...`

Comment: @ipatev_nn поддерживает

Comment: Значит ошибаюсь)